# XPath NodeList Values are Empty

Tags: xpath, nodelist

Using the following data I'm trying to parse and process the date values.

```
<Data>
<Data1 Study="R1979" MetaDataVersionOID="6713">
<Data2 Subject="4100">
    <SData Event="SCN" key="WK1[1]">
        <FormData Form="PEMD" FormKey="1">
            <ItemData Item="PM" Value="1"/>
            <ItemData Item="PE" Value="1"/>
            <ItemData Item="DATE" Value="2020-01-01"/>
        </FormData>
    </SData>
</Data2>
</Data1>
<Data1 Study="R1979" MetaDataVersionOID="6713">
<Data2 Subject="4100">
    <SData Event="WK1" key="WK1[1]">
        <FormData Form="PEMD" Formkey="1">
            <ItemData Item="PM" Value="1"/>
            <ItemData Item="PE" Value="1"/>
            <ItemData Item="DATE" Value="2019-12-18"/>
        </FormData>
    </SData>
</Data2>
</Data1>
</Data>
```

Using this code node value is null land date is empty:

```
strXPath =/Data/Data1/Data2[@Subject='4100']/SData/FormData[@Form='PEMD']/ItemData[@Item='DATE']
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) XPathUtil.getXPath().evaluate(strXPath, docODM, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    logger.info("node " + i);

    Node nodeElement = nodes.item(i);

    logger.info("node value: " + nodeElement.getNodeValue());

    String date = (String)XPathUtil.getXPath().evaluate("/ItemData/@Value", nodeElement, XPathConstants.STRING);

    logger.info("date: " + date);
}
```

The first strXPath yields this:

```
Element='<ItemData Item="DATE" Value="2020-01-01"/>'
Element='<ItemData Item="DATE" Value="2019-12-18"/>'
```

Retrieving the date Value for one element at a time using this should work:

```
/ItemData/@Value
```

And it does in the tester.

```
Attribute='Value=2020-01-01'
```

But node value above is null and date is empty and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your second XPath. Add `.` at the beginning of it to specify you're working from a context node and remove the `ItemData` part.

```
String date = (String)XPathUtil.getXPath().evaluate("./@Value", nodeElement, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Output :

```
['2020-01-01']
['2019-12-18']
```

Comment: Thanks but as I stated I was already getting the correct values from the /@Value path. The issue turned out to be the way our environment compiled the XPathFactory and other classes. I used Node.getAttributes() from the org.w3c.dom and it worked.

Comment: So it works with `/ItemData/@Value`, OK... In Python, `./@Value` should have been the way to go. I suppose it's related to Java and XPath factory. Glad you found something that works.

Answer (score 0):

I used Node.getAttributes() from the org.w3c.dom and it worked.